# Changing array of the object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux

I am mutating **products** array and in that, I am mutating **container** object of one element of the array, let's say **products[0]**. I am assigning a new object to the container object of the 0th element of the product. The code is given below. But instead of updating the container object into a given new object, it sets it to an array.

See element at index **0** of product array. Here is where I am setting **container** object to the new object. But here it sets an array to **container** object. See the code below. And also see the **container** object of the element at index **1**. At index ***1***, it is correct.

```
(10) products = [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:   container: (2) [{…}, {…}]
     id: 15
     markup_factor: "1.30"
     name: "Sohil Test Product"
     private: false
     profit_factor: "3.00"
     recipe: {id: 1, user: null, ingredients: Array(2), unit: "g", quantity: 4, …}
     sales_tax: "12.00"
     tags: [{…}]
     total_price: 17.47
     user: 3
     __proto__: Object

1:   container: {user: null, id: 22, components: Array(1), currency: "EUR", total_price: 0.15, …}
     id: 16
     markup_factor: "4.00"
     name: "demo product 24"
     private: false
     profit_factor: "4.00"
     recipe: {id: 38, user: 3, ingredients: Array(1), unit: "g", quantity: 0, …}
     sales_tax: "0.00"
     tags: []
     total_price: "9.12"
     user: 3
     __proto__: Object
2: {id: 21, user: 3, name: "DEMO PRODUCT", tags: Array(1), sales_tax: "2.00", …}
3: {id: 22, user: 3, name: "product 2", tags: Array(0), sales_tax: "4.00", …}
4: {id: 23, user: 3, name: "new product coming", tags: Array(1), sales_tax: "3.00", …}
5: {id: 24, user: 3, name: "new product", tags: Array(1), sales_tax: "0.00", …}
6: {id: 25, user: 3, name: "new product", tags: Array(2), sales_tax: "0.00", …}
7: {id: 26, user: 3, name: "sample test", tags: Array(0), sales_tax: "0.00", …}
8: {id: 27, user: 3, name: "new product demo", tags: Array(0), sales_tax: "0.00", …}
9: {id: 28, user: 3, name: "new product 3", tags: Array(0), sales_tax: "1.00", …}
length: 10
__proto__: Array(0)
```

The code for mutation is:

```
export const updateSelectedProduct = selectedContainer => (dispatch, getState) => {

  let { selectedProduct } = getState().product;
  let { products } = getState().product;
  for (var productList = 0; productList < products.length; productList++) {
    if (products[productList].id === selectedProduct.id) {
      const containerObj = {
        components: selectedContainer,
        currency: products[productList].container.currency,
        id: products[productList].container.id,
        name: null,
        user: null

      };  


       products[productList].container = containerObj;


    }
  }

};
```

Comment: The object contained in `containerObj` won't magically transform into an array of _two_ objects. Please add a [mcve] that shows the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have your first element is type of array:

```
container: (2) [{…}, {…}]
```

and the second element is object:

```
container: {user: null, id: 22, components: Array(1), currency: "EUR", total_price: 0.15, …}
```

So this is a reason why it sets it to an array.

What you can do is to get an object, not array for your first element and then your code will work. Let me show an example:

```js
const products = [
  {
 container : [{id: 1, currency: 'USD'}, {test: 'Hello, World:)'}],
 id: 15,
 markup_factor: "1.30",
 name: "Sohil Test Product",
 private: false,
 profit_factor: "3.00",
 recipe: {id: 1, user: null, ingredients: [], unit: "g", quantity: 4, },
 sales_tax: "12.00",
 tags: [{}],
 total_price: 17.47,
 user: 3
},
{
 container : {id: 2, currency: 'Another Currency'},
 id: 16,
 markup_factor: "4.00",
 name: "demo product 24",
 private: false,
 profit_factor: "4.00",
 recipe: {id: 38, user: 3, ingredients: [], unit: "g", quantity: 0, },
 sales_tax: "0.00",
 tags: [],
 total_price: "9.12",
 user: 3,
},
{id: 21, user: 3, name: "DEMO PRODUCT", tags: [], sales_tax: "2.00", },
{id: 22, user: 3, name: "product 2", tags: [], sales_tax: "4.00", },
{id: 23, user: 3, name: "new product coming", tags: [], sales_tax: "3.00", },
{id: 24, user: 3, name: "new product", tags: [], sales_tax: "0.00", },
];


products.forEach((el, index) => {
  let container = null;
  let containerObj = null;
  if (Array.isArray(el.container)
&& el.container.some(c=> c.currency && c.id)) {
container = el.container.find(c => c.currency && c.id);
containerObj = {
  components: container,
  currency: container.currency,
  id: container.id,
  name: null,
  user: null
};
  } else if(products[index].container && products[index].container.currency) {
containerObj = {
  components: el,
  currency: products[index].container.currency,
  id: products[index].container.id,
  name: null,
  user: null
};
  }
  products[index].container = containerObj;
});
console.log(products)
```